# Shut down/stop TCP but keep other protocols up?

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-protocols

We make a line of industrial manufacturing products which are controlled from software running on a PC.   The PC software, in turn, can be controlled from Android devices via a TCP connection, so out on the factory floor workers can use these Android devices as a remote controls for the manufacturing process.

One problem we have is that in congested networks, like at trade shows where we show these products off, the TCP connections between the Android and the PC often gets dropped.  We've just written software to detect dropped TCP connections from the Android and send a message to the PC via **UDP** that this has occurred, but we need to test it.

To aid in testing this I want a way to shut down or break TCP on the PC so I can simulate this condition.  I'd like to do this either as a simple C#/.Net program or, better yet, via a "DOS" command or something similar.  Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Define 'gets dropped'.

Comment: @EJP We're not sure but it only happens when the wifi spectrum  is very crowded like at trade shows.  Dropped wifi connections are very common at trade shows (look up Steve Jobs famous "I've got time..." speech at WWDC in 2010)  Basically we open a socket and are happily communicating away when packets just stop getting ACK'ed.   Closing and reopening the socket fixes it.   Why does it matter for my question?

Comment: Do you have control over the PC and Android software, in particular the implementation of the TCP communication protocol being used? If you have to send a UDP message to the PC to let it know a client has been dropped then the PC software is too dumb to detect the drop for itself. Any worthy TCP software needs to be able to handle that. Either enable keep-alives in TCP itself, or design a keep-alive command into your communication protocol. That allows both server and client detect dead connections so they can close their respective endpoints, and for a client to then attempt to reconnect.

Comment: To test your recovery logic, you can then block those keep-alives periodically and see what happens, or even implement a proxy that filters them for you so you don't have to keep making changes to the PC/Android software itself.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau : Remember - this is a PC talking with an Android device.  When you think "Android" think "battery powered".  Keep-alives are battery-killers, so they're impractical for an industrial device which has to run for a full shift on one charge.   So rather than trying to solve the larger problem, let's stick to the original question -  is there any way to turn off only the TCP protocol on a PC.